# Can we find functions $g_0,g_1, \dots, g_n$ such that $f_0g_0+f_1 g_1 + \cdots + f_n g_n =1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f_0, f_1, \dots, f_n$ be analytic functions on unit disc. Can we found analytic functions $g_0, g_1, \dots, g_n$ on unit disc such that $$f_0g_0+f_1 g_1 + \cdots + f_n g_n =1$$

This might be open problem. I heard it today from my professor of complex analysis.

### **Edit:**

I asked (finally) my profesor for this problem and "this" is the Corona Problem:

> Let $f_1, . . . , f_n$ be functions in $H^{\infty}$ such that $|f_1(z)|+· · ·+|f_n(z)| \ge \delta $ for all $|z| < 1$ and some $\delta > 0$. Then there exists functions $g_1, . . . , g_n$ in $H^{\infty}$ such that $$f_1(z)g_1(z) + · · · + f_n(z)g_n(z) ≡ 1.$$

It's proved by Lennart Carleson in 1962.

Comment: Obviously, if all the $f_k$ have a common zero this is impossible.

Comment: This is clearly false if $n=0$ and $f_0(z)=z$.

Comment: Do you mean meromorphic functions? Take $n=0$ and $f_0=z$.

Comment: It seems somewhat related to the [corona theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_theorem), but that is about bounded functions.

Comment: Probably I didn't understand my professor well. This is all I can remember. I will ask him next class (for 7 days).

Answer (score 2):

Holomorphic functions with pointwise addition and multiplication are an integral domain, so when at least one $f_n$ is not zero we can chose $g_n$ as it's meromorphic inverse.

So the  trivial case in which it is possible is when we have an $f_k$ without a zero in the unit circle (as $g=1/f_k$ will be holomorphic too)

The trivial case in which it doesn't work, is when all all $f_k$ have a common zero.

When every $f_k$ has an zero somewhere it is complicated. When $f_k$ is polynomial it will work, by chosing $g_k$ as polynomials.  Like for example when $f_0=x+1$ and $f_1= x$ we chose $g_0=-x-1$ and $g_1=x$ and have
$$-x^2+1+x^2=1$$

Bad luck this doesn't work so fine on laurent series, as essentiale we use the finte degree of a polynomial.

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks for your help.

P.S. I can't accept your answer because my question (yes, edited, but...) is different. And I found my answer. It's probably stupid for me, but don't be mad on me. I gave you (+1) :-)